# SidebarListStyle on Catalyst

Tags: ios14, xcode12, macos-big-sur

Goal:
Build SidebarListStyle on Catalyst

According to Apple, SidebarListStyle is available in Mac Catalyst 14.0+
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sidebarliststyle

What I get:
'SidebarListStyle' is unavailable in iOS
/SwiftUI.SidebarListStyle:5:15: 'SidebarListStyle' has been explicitly marked unavailable here

My setup:
iOS Deployment target: 14.1
Xcode Version 12.1 (12A7403)
macOS Big Sur 11.0 Beta (20A5395g)

Anyone had same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a version of the Xcode Beta from the Developer Site.

The regular version from the App Store does not have the correct SDK.